# автоматический скриншот сайта на Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, изображения, скриншот

Разрабатываю сайт на `Java EE`. Сделал автоскриншот сайта на `Selenium`. Всё работает. Но фигня в том что это на винде. Буду переносить сайт на `Ubuntu` (на хостинг). Стал вопрос как реализовать автоматический скриншот сайта. Подскажите утилиты которые это могут делать? Может для `Java EE` есть библиотеки.

**Решение:** `phantomjs`

Comment: пожалуйста, уточните (прямо в вопросе), чем именно вас перестал устраивать selenium.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin он устраивает меня. но возможно ли в нём делать скриншот экрана на Linux.

Ответ - можно `phantomjs`

Comment: @Tsyklop опубликуйте решение ответом, отметьте галочкой и удалите из вопроса, если вопрос решён.